# routing error showing that No route matches [POST] "/admin/locations/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ROR when i edit my location it will gives me following error
`No route matches [POST] "/admin/locations/1"`

here i am using rails 3.2.12

this is my location controller

```
class Admin::LocationsController < ApplicationController


def index
    @location= Location.order("location desc")
end

def new
    @location=Location.new
end

def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])
    if @location.save
     # flash[:notice] = 'Location is successfully added in to list.'
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end

def edit
   @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    if @location.update_attributes(params[:location])
      #flash[:notice] = 'Category is successfully updated.'
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'index'
    end
end

end
```

this is my edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit Location</h2>
<%= simple_form_for(:location, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @location.id}) do |f| %>
    <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>  
    <%= submit_tag("Update",) %> <%= link_to("cancle", {:action => 'index'} )%>

<%end%>
```

and this is my route.rb

```
GuestHouse::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :customers

  namespace :admin do
    resources :locations
  end
```

and in my index.html.erb  as
    <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => location.id}, :class => 'btn btn-info')%>

Comment: `“/admin/locations/1”` should be `GET` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for(:location, 
  :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @location.id},
  :method => 'put' ) do |f| %>
```

Pass method in `simple_form_for`

Answer (score 0):

For an edit form, you likely want to be using the `PUT` method instead of `POST`. It looks like you are using [SimpleForm][1], though, which normally would handle constructing the path for a given model for you. Is there any reason you are not passing your `Location` instance in your call to `simple_form_for`? I would expect something like the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @location do |f| %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your routes for admin/location like the following.

```
      admin_locations GET    /admin/locations(.:format)            admin/locations#index
                      POST   /admin/locations(.:format)            admin/locations#create
   new_admin_location GET    /admin/locations/new(.:format)        admin/locations#new
  edit_admin_location GET    /admin/locations/:id/edit(.:format)   admin/locations#edit
       admin_location GET    /admin/locations/:id(.:format)        admin/locations#show
                      PUT    /admin/locations/:id(.:format)        admin/locations#update
                      DELETE /admin/locations/:id(.:format)        admin/locations#destroy
```

so if you want to send the form to **'update'** action, you should mention the path like below.

```
<%= simple_form_for @location, :url => admin_location_path(@location),:html => { :method => "post"} do |f| %>
```